# Azure ARM: How to get the display name of Azure `location`?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I know in ARM template: we can use `[resourceGroup().location]` to get location code (Eg: eastus).

But how to get the displayName (Eg: East US) in ARM template?

Any suggestion would be appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

#### Get available locations in ARM template

Different resource types are supported in different locations. To get the supported locations for a resource type, use Azure PowerShell or Azure CLI.

***Using Poweshell :***

```
((Get-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Batch).ResourceTypes `
  | Where-Object ResourceTypeName -eq batchAccounts).Locations
```

[image]

***Using Azure CLI:***

```
az provider show \
  --namespace Microsoft.Batch \
  --query "resourceTypes[?resourceType=='batchAccounts'].locations | [0]" \
  --out table
```

[image]

Comment: The question is about getting the location name in ARM template using template function and not through PowerShell or CLI.